# Base class's destructor called without destroying the base class!

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, ctor-initializer

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
        int i;
        A() {cout<<"A()"<<endl;}
        ~A() {cout<<"~A()"<<endl;}
};
class B:public A
{
public:
        int j;
        B(): j(10)
        {
                this->i=20;
                this->~A();
        }
};

int main()
{
        B abc;
        cout<<"i="<<abc.i<<" j="<<abc.j<<endl;
}//main
```

Two questions:

1. How come A's destructor gets called like an ordinary function instead of destroying the object? (or is it some kind of rule that the base class will be destroyed only if the child class's destructor calls the base class's destructor?) I was trying out this sample code to find out how the destructor works. So if simply calling the destructor function does not destruct the object, then there is obviously some other kind of call that calls the destructor and only then the object is destructed. What's so special in that kind of call and what call is it?
2. Is there a way to have an initialization list for A in B's constructor? Something like this:

   ```
   class B:public A
   { 
       B(): j(10), A():i(20) {}
   };
   ```

Comment: Can you present code without Undefined Behavior, that exhibits whatever the apparent problem is? E.g., code without an explicit destructor call?

Comment: -1 don't write stupid code (i.e. destroying your own base class in a constructor)

Comment: What on Earth is `this->~A();` for? Surely you [should understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) what they do before you use them? :)

Comment: @Alf: Explicitly calling the dectructor doesn't exhibit UB, does it? Just to make sure. (provided the object isn't used any more and provided it is not in constructor)

Comment: @Jan and @GMan: It would have been stupid code if I was using the same code while building an application. Here, I was just testing out the working of destructors to understand how C++ works. What I really wanted to know was how the destructor function works. ie: will just calling the destructor destruct the object or not. Apparently here, calling the destructor isn't enough. Something else happens under the hood. I want to know what that is.

Comment: @Armen: the object is used after being destroyed. That in itself is UB. Then it's destroyed for the second time by the implicit destructor call (assuming it occurs in spite of the first UB). Which is also UB. Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nav: no, your understanding of "destroyed" is just wrong. When an object's destructor is called, the object is destroyed. You seem to believe that the memory it resided in evaporates entirely, but that never happens. The object no longer exists, but some garbage data is typically left over by the object, and if you're willing to break the rules of C++ and invoke undefined behavior, then you can read those leftover bytes, and they'll *look like* the object, and because there are no runtime checks on whether you're accessing a valid object, you can often *treat them* as an object. Which you do.

It's illegal, it's undefined behavior, but in practice it often works.

Once again, a destructor does not physically vaporize the memory. Your RAM still has the same capacity after a destructor has executed. Conceptually, the object no longer exists once the destructor has run. But the data it contained is still there in memory.

Comment: +1 for understanding the OP's problem with the whole "destruction" concept.

Answer (score 5):

1. The base class's destructor **should** be virtual. Here, as it's created on the stack, it's not problem, but anyway..
2. No, but you can call the `class A()` constructor in the initialize list of B's constructor, like this:
   `B(): A( .. ), ...`

---

```
A* a = new B();
//..
delete a;
```

will **not** call B's destructor unless `class A` destructor *is virtual*. That's why STL containers should not be derived - theirs destructors are not virtual.

Comment: Nope. Having the base class's constructor as virtual does not destruct A.

Comment: There's no need to have a virtual destructor unless an object of a child class is destroyed through a pointer to the base class.

Comment: No, the base class' destructor is not required to be virtual. But it's difficult to say what the original code & problem was. The presented code just has Undefined Behavior.

Comment: **@Nav** - noone talks about constructors, but destructors. And don't call `this->~A();` in B's constructor ...  **@Victor** - yep, you're right about pointers. Here there's no such problem, as the object is not created using new, but still.. **@Alf** - Yes, it's not requered, but it should be, right? Or, there could be memory leaks in some situations. And I agree with the Undefined Behavior (:

Comment: I was just testing it out to find out how these things work. For me, knowing the concepts from the ground level is very important. Innovative testing/experimenting with basic concepts teaches me a lot.

Comment: What I really wanted to know was how the destructor function works. ie: will just calling the destructor destruct the object or not. Apparently here, calling the destructor isn't enough. Something else happens under the hood. I want to know what that is.

Comment: -1 for replacing original error (corrected) with "STL containers should not be derived". That's an urban legend. One seldom if ever allocate such containers dynamically, it serves no purpose. Cheers,

Comment: I didn't get that `replacing original error (corrected) with "STL containers should not be derived"`. Anyway, OK for the STL containers and creating the dynamically, I agree with you, but still ..

Answer (score 5):

1. Destructor is like any other normal function which you *can* call (but you should never do it unless you use a placement new). When you call `delete` on a object two things happen: Destructor is called for cleanup and then `operator delete` is called to release the memory allocated for the object. Here the second step is not happening.
2. No, you can not call it like that. What you can do is some thing like this:

   class A
   {
     public:
     A(int n) : i(n){}
   };

   class B : public A
   {
     public:
      B() : A(20), j(10){}
   };

Comment: A situation where it's acceptable to call the destructor is when you're managing the underlying object memory yourself, and created the object using placement new. Of course, it's exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 3):

For point:

1. This is an undefined behaviour but only ~A() is called though an instance of class B because ~A() is not declared virtual. See more on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).
2. No. For derived classes, first call your parent class, then assign parameters.

For point 1) on Wikipedia:

> having no virtual destructor, while
>   deleting an instance of class B will
>   correctly call destructors for both B
>   and A if the object is deleted as an
>   instance of B, an instance of B
>   deleted via a pointer to its base
>   class A will produce undefined
>   behaviour.

Example (for point 2):

```
B(): A(), j(10) {}
```

or

```
B(): A() {j = 10;}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Destructor calling order in C++ is reverse order of the constructor calling order. So first derived class object get destroy and then base class object.

2) No.

Answer (score 2):

In the code that you are giving, you are indeed destroying the base class and as such `i`. Calling a destructor and then using the dead object is undefined behavior - it may work or it may crash.

Should `i` was something that is more complex that an `int` (for example a `vector`), trying to do anything with that would probably result in a crash.

Answer (score 2):

If you call ~SomeClass() yourself, explicitly, the destructor function will be called.  Which leaves the object (in this case, the base class part of the object) in a destroyed state.

Since the destructor is not virtual, the destructor of derived classes will not be called, but base classes of SomeClass will be destroyed too.

Trying to find out if A is really destroyed by just using the i member, is not a good test.  In fact, you can't test this, since using the object results in undefined behavour.  It may work, or it may not (in your case, it probably will print "i=20 j=10", but i is already destroyed).